# Use GET parameters as query filters

Tags: django

I have a URL with parameters such as:

```
field1__lt=7&field2__contains=bar
```

I understand how to get these values from the cleaned_data dict, but how can I put them into filter() statements? filter doesn't seem to like the key being a string.

This is for trusted users only, so there are no security concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dict unpacking. If you have a dict like `{'field1__lt':7, 'field2__contains':'bar'}` in a variable `lookups`, then you can write `filter(**lookups)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass few arguments in .filter method? Then you will need to use Q objects. So, something like this will work correctly.

```
MyModel.objects.filter(Q(field1__lt=7)&Q(field2__contains=bar))
```